# Word for when someone tries to be attractive but fails

Tags: single-word-requests

I was reading a book when I saw this word, and when I searched for it, the definition was along the lines of 'when someone tries to be attractive but fails'.

I don't know if I'm remembering it incorrectly or what, but I skimmed through the book and could not find it. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: Lipstick on a pig?

Comment: Similarly, "Mutton dressed as Lamb", though neither of these expressions solves the OP's quest for a single word.

Comment: Also try looking at *pretentious* and its synonyms, and *wannabe*.

Comment: I suggest there is no such single word,  and aparente001's lipstick on a pig or Duckspindle's mutton dressed as lamb are as close as you'll get.

Either way, in my view word, phrase or expression requests should be promoted to their own specialised community, perhaps named 'Vocabulary.'

Comment: There are a lot of expressions such as "mutton dressed as lamb", "lipstick on a pig", "tarty", etc, meaning specifically a woman dressed in an overly sexualised way to try and appear attractive but who is still judged unattractive because she's too fat, old, ignorant of customs, etc. That is more specific than the question.

Comment: If that is the definition, you're probably not looking for a noun indicating the person trying to be attractive. The "when" seems to indicate a situation or attempt. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 2):

A single word for this seems tricky. A somewhat close match is "*[chichi](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/chichi)*"

> trying too hard to be decorated in a stylish or attractive way and therefore having no real style or beauty

There are also [related words](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/chichi) (which do not match your definition but could lead in the right direction): *frilly, pretentious, splashy*

On the off chance that you misremember the definition, a word for trying to be attractive (and not failing) is "*[peacocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peacocking)*":

> when a male uses ostentatious clothing and behavior to attract a female and to stand out from other competing males, with the intention to become more memorable and interesting

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know this meaning of _chichi_. Also note that, it is a slang word for 'a woman's breasts'. It comes from Japanese [ちち (chichi)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%A1%E3%81%A1#Japanese). Good answer, upvoted.

Comment: @ermanen I always assumed, based on nothing but the sound of the word and the Italian reputation for style, that 'chichi' meaning 'unsuccessfully aspirational' came from Italian.

Comment: @BoldBen To clarify: I've meant the slang usage of _chichi_ for 'breasts' comes from Japanese _ちち (chichi)_. However, _chichi_ in the answer comes from French _chichi_ meaning 'affected manners' (1886 in _faire du chichi_).

Answer (score 0):

A simple, but perhaps somewhat informal, word to describe this would be "[Tryhard](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/tryhard#:%7E:text=Definition%20of%20tryhard&text=a%20person%20who%20participates%20in,a%20breath%2C%20and%20chill%20out)". (Dictionary.com)

Comment: Now give us an example of this used in a sentence.  Also, name the dictionary and then make that title a hyperlink.

Comment: In my mind, tryhard doesn't evoke the idea of failing to be attractive on its own.